# How to print '<!DOCTYPE html>'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My client requests a page from a server written in python 3.
The server return an html page that is presented by client.

Therefore, I did a *dummy.html* page and when client asks for it, my python reads it and returns it to the client:

```
filename = "dummy.html" 
fh = open(filename, 'rt')
line = fh.readline()
while line:
    print(line) 
    line = fh.readline()
fh.close()
```

However, this code does not read the `<!DOCTYPE html>` that is placed in the top of my *dummy.html* file (and thus, things like bootstrap don't work for me...).

I also tried printing it manually `print('<!DOCTYPE html>')` but that also does not work.

```
print('<!DOCTYPE html>')               <---- IT IS PRINTED TO SDOUT BUT WHEN PRINTED TO CLIENT, THE PAGE DOES NOT HAVE THIS LINE ....
filename = CURRENTPATH+"\\..\\su.html"
fh = open(filename, 'rt')
line = fh.readline()
print('hello')
print('<'+'!'+'DOCTYPE html>')
while line:
    print(line) 
    line = fh.readline()
fh.close()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't get what you want. When I try your code, it works without any issue for me.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your result in Python 3.4.3 and can't; the `<!DOCTYPE html>` line is output properly. Perhaps you need to look closer at your input file?

Comment: When I print in via development framework, I see it is printed ok. However, when my client request the file, I see that something is wrong... when I do "View source", there is no "<!DOCTYPE html>" at the top of the file... somewhy it is missing... Thanks!

Comment: Which Python 3 version are you using?

Comment: `print('<!DOCTYPE html>')` works perfectly in both python2 and 3. Checked it with python 2.7.10 and python 3.4.2

Comment: I am using 3.4.3. but it does not print... ( I mean it prints when I try on cosule, but the client wont get it...).  Please see my edited question

Comment: If your server is set up to serve *.py files using CGI (or whatever), then your print command will work just fine. Sometimes we need to explore the basics before attempting to learn a new framework such as Django.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to reimplement a web server in Python. Please consider using an existing web framework, such as Django (https://www.djangoproject.com/), Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) or Pyramid (http://www.pylonsproject.org/), which will do most of the work for you (including built-in support for a wide variety of HTML templating libraries, and actual performance).

As for your actual answer, a bare `print` statement prints to `stdout`, as expected. You need, instead, to write to the file-like object whose contents will be sent to the client (is it a socket? a file? who knows? stop reinventing the wheel).

Comment: Ypu are probably right, but it seems to me that learning a framework just for this tiny task would be too much...

Comment: It'll take you less time to learn and set up Flask than it will take you to figure out and solve that problem *and all the others that come with reimplementing a web framework from scratch*. For example, did you know your app probably can't handle more than 1 connection at a time?

Comment: What do you mean? Isnt it possible that 2 users will ask for a certain (same page)?